pytest ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easynmt' in Jenkins
pytest cannot find module easynmt when I run pytest
my-proj
├── src
│   ├── run.py
│   ├── __init__.py (empty)
└── tests
│   ├── test_run.py
│   ├── test_requirements.txt
|___setup.py
|___conftest.py (empty)
|___pytest.ini 

setup.py:
install_requires=['easynmt==2.0.2', 'torch==2.2.2']

run.py:
from easynmt import EasyNMT, models

pytest.ini:
[pytest]
pythonpath = .

test_requirements.txt:
pytest
torch==2.2.2
easynmt==2.0.2

Error:
13:06:26  /usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
13:06:26      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
13:06:26  tests/test_run.py:4: in <module>
13:06:26      from an_ml_easynmt_model import oversatt
13:06:26  src/__init__.py:1: in <module>
13:06:26      from an_ml_easynmt_model.run import oversatt
13:06:26  src/run.py:1: in <module>
13:06:26      from easynmt import EasyNMT, models
13:06:26  E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easynmt'

Actually pytest work locally but not in jenkins. Tests is run in jenkins with following bash-script:
  sh '''#!/bin/bash
      python -m venv ./testvenv
      source ./testvenv/bin/activate
      pip install -U pip
      pip install -U setuptools
      pip install -U wheel
      pip install -r ./tests/test_requirements.txt
      pip install -e .
      deactivate && source ./testvenv/bin/activate
      hash -r
      python -m site
      pytest tests 
      deactivate
    '''

(I found the deactivate/source "dance" here How do I use pytest with virtualenv?)
Tried putting empty init-files, init-files with src-manipulations, no conftest.py-file, tried running python -m pytest, and more. I'm lost.
UPDATE:
There was som erlier errors in the log that I suppose I need to look into first. Does these errors mean som of my dependencies require another version of torch than my projects requirements? "from versions: none" seemes fishy:
10:33:55  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.2.2 (from versions: none)
10:33:55  ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.2.2

I have seen a similiar print in another project but in that error message there was versions to choose from:
09:21:23  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.0 (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2)
09:21:23  ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.0


The default shell in Jenkins in sh and you cannot use source with it.
Try changing the shell in Jenkins configuration:
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Shell -> Shell executable.
Setting this to /bin/bash will make source work.
